# It is legal to recreate Camp Half-Blood in my own writing?

Tags: fantasy, copyright, legal

"Camp Half-Blood" is the name of a location in a book series of the same name from the author Rick Riordan. It is legal to recreate this location in my own writing, even if the original elements (ie not based on public domain elements) aren't excluded?

Comment: What you say "recreate this location", you mean exactly identical to how it's portrayed in the Rick Riordan series? Is there any reason you want to do this?

Comment: Not necessarily exact, but similar.

Comment: Similar in what ways, then? Can you edit the question to clarify the intended similarities and differences?

Comment: You also failed to answer my question about *why* you want to recreate Camp Half-Blood in your writing, rather than inventing a location of your own making to fill the same role. Looking at your questions both here and elsewhere on the network, I am *extremely* concerned about the amount of inspiration you seem to be trying to take from Riordan; almost all of your questions seem to revolve around whether you can be sued for borrowing one element or another from his works (or even [his actual name](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/66898/23927)).

Comment: Similar questions have been asked and answered multiple times on this site. You can find them if you browse through [the copyright related questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright).